# Can the Spiral Knights upgrades in the starter pack activated "later"?

Tags: spiral-knights

The Spiral Knights starter pack includes weapon and trinket upgrades. It's totally unclear if they are immediately activated as you buy it, or if they are like a "token" which you can activate when you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like when they are purchased in-game for energy, the Weapon Upgrade, Token Upgrade, and Heat Amplifiers included in the Starter Pack are actual items that must be activated, consuming them, to take effect.

Comment: Thanks :) AFAIK those in the starter pack can't be sold to other players, though.